# Docker, why does it fail to access my other package in a java program

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, java-11, java-package

I'm deeply sorry since the answer may be existing already but I've failed to found it yet and the similar question part of stack overflow pointed me to some python question that doesn't really help me to understand,

So here I am:
I've done a very simple java program doing some maths and I'm trying to get it to run my functions defined in my "main" package into a "test" package, while doing it through eclipse compilation there is no problem, next step being setting up a dockerfile to allow me to keep using it everywhere (trying to learn docker)

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8u111-jdk-alpine


COPY . /usr/src/javafactorielle


WORKDIR /usr/src/javafactorielle

RUN javac src/javafactorielle/main/Operations.java
RUN javac src/javafactorielle/test/Main.java

CMD [java, Main, 4]
```

I've got no issue importing from a package to another in eclipse and compiling it successfully
[image: Here is the structure of my Java project being: src/ (javafactorielle.main/Operations.java) || (javafactorielle.test/Main.java)]

But when I try to build the dockerfile I got the following error:

```
------
 > [5/5] RUN javac src/javafactorielle/test/Main.java:
0.785 src/javafactorielle/test/Main.java:3: error: package javafactorielle.main does not exist
0.785 import javafactorielle.main.Operations;
0.785                            ^
0.825 src/javafactorielle/test/Main.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
0.825                   int result = Operations.FactoOf(number);
0.825                                ^
0.825   symbol:   variable Operations
0.825   location: class Main
0.835 2 errors
------
```

Can anyone here help me figure out where did I messed up?

I know I would probably be able to get away with it by putting my operations class in the same package as my tests but that would be super messy so I would prefer not to do that
Since I'm really a beginner when it comes to docker I would appreciate if you could keep your explanations as simple as possible (and link some doc if you can, so I may learn more around those issues)

Another question: Since I'm using different package:
Do I have to look at docker compose for this?

EDITS:
"Try removing the statement import javafactorielle.main.Operations –
Klitos Kyriacou"
Well it didn't helped and I had to explicitely cast the path to the said class when using it

Comment: Try removing the statement `import javafactorielle.main.Operations`

Comment: `javac` by default will write a `*.class` file to the current directory.  You need a `javac -d` option to write into a directory tree mirroring the Java package hierarchy, and a `javac -cp` option or `$CLASSPATH` environment variable for the second compilation to find the first file.  Using a higher-level build tool like Gradle or Maven seems more complex, but it will solve problems like this out-of-the-box.  (I don't think this is Docker-specific at all and you'd have the same problem running the `javac` command directly.)

Comment: Try running `javac` from the src directory: `WORKDIR /usr/src/javafactorielle/src`

Comment: I don't know Docker, but (assuming the WORKDIR part is right) something like this seems to be called for
`RUN javac -d bin src/javafactorielle/main/Operations.java
RUN javac -d bin src/javafactorielle/test/Main.java
CMD [java, -cp, bin, javafactorielle.test.Main, 4]`

Comment: @g00se running `javac -d bin src/javafactorielle/main/Operations.java` would still mean the `src` directory is taken as part of the package name. It would have to be `javac -d bin  -cp src javafactorielle/main/Operations.java`. Or just cd to the `src` directory itself before issuing the commands.

Comment: @k314159 you're right about the `-cp` in the `javac` command, but the package is not a problem per se: `goose@t410:/tmp$ javac -d bin -cp bin src/javafactorielle/main/Operations.java
goose@t410:/tmp$ javac -d bin -cp bin src/javafactorielle/test/Main.java
goose@t410:/tmp$ java -cp bin javafactorielle.test.Main
I'm Ops!` So - put `-cp bin` in all commands

Comment: @g00se if you use `src` as the classpath, then you can do: `javac -d bin -cp src javafactorielle/main/Operations.java` and it will automatically find and compile the dependent class `Main.java`. But if you use `bin` as the classpath, you'll have to compile `Main.java` first.

Comment: Good to keep src out of any classpath explicitly. But actually it can be simplified to `javac -d bin  src/javafactorielle/test/*.java src/javafactorielle/main/*.java`